# Send passive federation request to ADFS 2.0 for SAML 2.0 token

Tags: saml, adfs2.0

I have a working ADFS machine. I want to construct a passive request that will generate a saml 2.0 token.

the following request for saml 2.0 token:

https://adfstest.cld.sr/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FPro%2FFederatedLogin.mvc&wauth=urn:oasis:names:tc:**SAML:2.0**:am:password

generates the error: "Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.NoAuthenticationContextException: MSIS7040: None of the requested authentication types are supported by the server."

yet if I change the request to a request for saml 1.0:

https://adfstest.cld.sr/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FPro%2FFederatedLogin.mvc&wauth=urn:oasis:names:tc:**SAML:1.0**:am:password

It works but the token generated by ADFS is SAML 1.0.

What is the correct form to construct a request for passive federation with SAML 2.0  tokens?

Answer (score 2):

AD FS 2.0 does not support SAML 2.0-based IDP-initiated SSO to a WIF relying party application. 
The url you used in a ws-federation request and as such only saml 1.1 will be returned by ADFS.